# Change color of numbers in listings but not inside of identifiers

Tags: listings

I want to write C++ code in LaTeX using the `listings` package. The problem is that I want to change the color numbers in code (integers, doubles...). The only solution I found was this:

```
\lstdefinestyle{customc}{
    belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=L,
    xleftmargin=\parindent,
    showstringspaces=false,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    language=C++,
    morekeywords={Mat, cvtColor,one},
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},
    stringstyle=\color{orange},
 }
\lstset{literate=%
    {0}{{{\color{red}0}}}1
    {1}{{{\color{red}1}}}1
    {2}{{{\color{red}2}}}1
    {3}{{{\color{red}3}}}1
    {4}{{{\color{red}4}}}1
    {5}{{{\color{red}5}}}1
    {6}{{{\color{red}6}}}1
    {7}{{{\color{red}7}}}1
    {8}{{{\color{red}8}}}1
    {9}{{{\color{red}9}}}1
}
```

But this solution give me this:

[image: result code]

Some numbers in variables are put in color too, but I don't want this. Someone knows another form of putting different color number in code?

Answer (score 2):

I know only some tricky code with escaping the digits:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstdefinestyle{customc}{
    belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=L,
    xleftmargin=\parindent,
    showstringspaces=false,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    language=C++,
    morekeywords={Mat, cvtColor,one},
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},
    stringstyle=\color{orange},
    escapechar=\%,
}
\def\N#1{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=customc]
area = moment.m00
Point2f(x,y), %\N1%, %\N1,% 
\end{lstlisting}

\begingroup
\catcode`\0=13 \def0{\textcolor{red}{\string0}}
\catcode`\1=13 \def1{\textcolor{red}{\string1}}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=customc]
area = moment.m00
Point2f(x,y), %1%, %1%, %0%,  
\end{lstlisting}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Red_Cloud Ok it could be a solution but it's very convoluted I mean there must be another easier way. Maybe another package like minted or other.